# How to get rid of unwanted constraint added by UIStackView?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints, interface-builder, uistackview

I have a segmented control within a (vertical) stack view and want its leading and trailing edges to have some distance from the left and right boundaries of the stack view.

I have tried defining a width constraint to do this and have tried trailing and leading space constraints, but at runtime they get broken bc the system is not able to "simultaneously satisfy constraints".  It is pretty clear from the console what the conflicting constraints are, but I did not add (see pic below) the ones that bind the segmented control to the left and right edge of its UIStackView container, therefore I do not know how to get rid of them.  The system breaks the constraint that I want to keep.

I should be clear that I don't necessarily require a width constraint for the UISegmentedControl -- trailing and leading space constraints would serve also.  To be utterly clear I need to be able to control the width of the segmented control.

Notice $WIDTH-SEGCTRL in the console output below.  It is from the identifier I defined in the constraint in Interface Builder.

```
2018-11-29 10:43:56.323503-0600 [21479:18697482] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000291440 H:[UIStackView:0x7f96373120d0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':SectionHeaderView:0x7f9637311e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040002985b0 H:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7f96373120d0]   (active, names: '|':SectionHeaderView:0x7f9637311e20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004913f0 '$WIDTH-SEGCTRL' UISegmentedControl:0x7f9637312d90.width == 280   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400029af90 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' SectionHeaderView:0x7f9637311e20.width == 320   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000486720 'UISV-alignment' UIStackView:0x7f96373122d0.leading == UISegmentedControl:0x7f9637312d90.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000486770 'UISV-alignment' UIStackView:0x7f96373122d0.trailing == UISegmentedControl:0x7f9637312d90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000486680 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7f96373120d0.leading == UIStackView:0x7f96373122d0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6040004866d0 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIStackView:0x7f96373122d0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7f96373120d0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004913f0 '$WIDTH-SEGCTRL' UISegmentedControl:0x7f9637312d90.width == 280   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Below are pics of before and after I add the width constraint that generates the problem.  You can see that Xcode regards the 280 width constraint as something it is unable to carry out. It regards the segmented control as bound to the edges, but I cannot figure out why.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Are you adding other elements? If not, no real reason to use stack views.

Comment: @DonMag, the reason I'm using a stack view is because the UILabel (in green) has to display html (via conversion to NSAttributedString) and often the html is more than can be displayed on one line.  Thus the label needs to expand vertically, dynamically, to display all its contents. Btw the view you see there is used as a section header view in a table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with your stack view layout...

For the Vertical Stack View, set `Alignment: Center`

For the Horizontal Stack View, set `Width` equal to Vertical Stack View Width

For the Segmented Control, set `Width` equal to Vertical Stack View Width with a constant of `-40`, which will leave 20-pts padding on each side. Adjust the constant to your liking, or set the Multiplier to 0.9 to make the segmented control 90% of the width.

[image]

Comment: Thx. I may need a bit of help trying this.  Vertical stack view alignment is now center.  But IB only allowing me to set horizontal stack view width constraint to a constant number.  The constraint's First item is "Stack View.Width" and the Relation is "Equal", but don't see where to specify the "Vertical Stack View Width" as you put it.

Comment: In the Document Outline pane, Ctrl-Click-Drag from "H-Stack" to "V-Stack" - that should pop up a menu where you can select Equal Widths. Same with the seg control... Ctrl-Click-Drag to "V-Stack", select Equal Widths, then change either the Constant or the Multiplier

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Much thanks, and I'll mark as correct.  I didn't know (obviously) that those ctrl-click options were available.  They seem kinda buried to be honest. Is there any other way, besides programmatically, to create such constraints?

Comment: Ctrl-Click-Drag is generally how you create constraints related to other objects. Normally, it's done in the view/layout itself - Ctrl-Click-Drag from a view to a button, for example. When you have a lot of objects, or when they're embedded in other views (including stack views) it can get difficult to get the right object in the designer -- so it can be easier to do it in the Document Outline pane.